# C# programming on macOS

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, development

I am looking for a C# programming compiler on macOS that is a good value.

Could you give me any advice?

Answer (score 24):

In [April 2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/mac/), Microsoft released [Visual Studio for Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/mac/installation). Visual Studio **Community** is free for students, open-source and individual developers.

It supports development of the following:

- Mobile with .NET: Android, iOS, tvOS, watchOS
- Mac desktop apps
- .NET applications (in C# and F# by default)
- ASP.NET Web applications
- Cross-platform Unity games

Minimum Requirements:

- macOS El Capitan 10.11
- Xcode 8.2
- An Apple ID (for signing into Xcode)

For [iOS development](https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/mac/installation), macOS Sierra 10.12 and Xcode 8.3 are required.

Comment: It also supports .NET standard, not just core.

Comment: Visual studio is an editor and doesn’t really compile anything. Wouldn’t this be more correct to list Xcode alone for a compiler? I guess it depends how much the OP wants an environment IDE or really wants just to compile for free or low cost.

Comment: @bmike You are thinking of Visual Studio Code which is just an editor. Visual Studio for Mac is a full IDE and includes parts beyond the 'editor' for compiling C# code that does not come with Xcode.

Comment: Visual Studio Code's a good point.  @thaimin's correct that it starts off as an editor upon initial download, but it becomes a full-blown IDE after a few clicks (specifically, the clicks to download the C# compiler, syntax highlighting, project management, etc. add-ins, which are linked within the editor itself).  So, it can be called an editor, or an IDE that has incremental installations.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac also runs perfectly well with XCode 8.2.1 and macOS 10.11. I believe your quoted requirements only apply for [iOS development](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation).

Answer (score 13):

The Mono project maintains a cross-platform C#/.net environment which works well on macOS.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/

Answer (score 7):

For compiler only I recommend to use [.net core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) with editor of choice. I use [VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) quite a lot, but you can use Sublime, Atom, etc.

As for IDE, I recommend to try [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) instead of VS for mac. Unfortunately, it has only trial. It provides same functionality as VS for mac.

Comment: Rider is version 1 as per date of my comment. Gratis for open source. Pay otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/). It's an official Microsoft product, so it should run C# quite well. When you have it installed, click on the last large button in the sidebar to get extensions, and search for C#. (There's also a Windows version.)

Answer (score 0):

I have been running the new Beta of Visual Studio for Mac on my new M1 pro max MacBook and it works well. I have also preferred the UI and run-times of CodeRunner 4, which is available through the App Store and allows running a variety of different languages.
I have only really used C# in it, but it’s error detection and corrections are very similar to VS, just no direct links to the Microsoft C# doc’s, but that isn’t difficult to work around!